# Store bot conversation to Azure sql database.Bot response not recording

Tags: c#, sql, azure, botframework, bots

I created a bot using the Botframework v3, that logs the conversation into a azure sql database. It works using the bot emulator. The questions that the bot is recorded and the user response is recorded in the azure sql db.

However, when i deployed the bot from visual studio to azure, using the bot registration channel. (I have deployed other different types bots many times and it usually works) When i use the bot in (test web chat) azure portal it fails--get the message-"sorry my bot is having issues" and the message that the user types fails to send.

The message that gets sent/what the user types **does** get recorded in the sql database. However the questions that the bot asks **does not get recorded** in the sql db.

SqlActivityogger class:

```
public class SqlActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
    {
    SqlConnection connection;

    public SqlActivityLogger(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        this.connection = conn;
    }
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        string fromId = activity.From.Id;
        string toId = activity.Recipient.Id;
        string message = activity.AsMessageActivity().Text;

        //when creating the sql database make sure you create a table userChatLog table in the db in portal.azure.com
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO userChatLog(fromId, toId, message) VALUES (@fromId,@toId,@message)";

        // Passing the fromId, toId, message to the the user chatlog table 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromId", fromId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toId", toId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);



        // Insert to Azure sql database
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Debug.WriteLine("Insertion successful of message: " + activity.AsMessageActivity().Text);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //setting up sql string connection string

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlbuilder.DataSource = "##########";
        sqlbuilder.UserID = "#####";
        sqlbuilder.Password = "#####";
        sqlbuilder.InitialCatalog = "######";

        connection = new SqlConnection(sqlbuilder.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection success");


        Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<SqlActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency().WithParameter("conn", connection);
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {

        connection.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection to database closed");
    }

}
```

Sandwich class

```
public enum SandwichOptions
{
    BLT, BlackForestHam, BuffaloChicken, ChickenAndBaconRanchMelt, ColdCutCombo, MeatballMarinara,
    OvenRoastedChicken, RoastBeef, RotisserieStyleChicken, SpicyItalian, SteakAndCheese, SweetOnionTeriyaki, Tuna,
    TurkeyBreast, Veggie
};
public enum LengthOptions { SixInch, FootLong };
public enum BreadOptions { NineGrainWheat, NineGrainHoneyOat, Italian, ItalianHerbsAndCheese, Flatbread };
public enum CheeseOptions { American, MontereyCheddar, Pepperjack };
public enum ToppingOptions
{
    Avocado, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
    Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
};
public enum SauceOptions
{
    ChipotleSouthwest, HoneyMustard, LightMayonnaise, RegularMayonnaise,
    Mustard, Oil, Pepper, Ranch, SweetOnion, Vinegar
};

[Serializable]
public class SandwichOrder
{
    public SandwichOptions? Sandwich;
    public LengthOptions? Length;
    public BreadOptions? Bread;
    public CheeseOptions? Cheese;
    public List<ToppingOptions> Toppings;
    public List<SauceOptions> Sauce;

    public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<SandwichOrder> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await context.PostAsync("This is the end of the form, you would give a final confirmation, and then start the ordering process as needed.");
        };

        return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                .Message("Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
                .OnCompletion(processOrder)
                .Build();
    }
};
```

Appreciate the help. I have been trying to figure this out for long time now and don't understand why this is not working.

Update:
After using ngrok to debug i get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.",
  "exceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at FormBot.Models.SqlActivityLogger.<LogAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\\FormSqlTest1-src\\Models\\SqlActivityLogger.cs:line 42
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\CSharp\\Library\\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\\ConnectorEx\\IActivityLogger.cs:line 108
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\CSharp\\Library\\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac\\Dialogs\\Conversation.cs:line 182
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\CSharp\\Library\\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac\\Dialogs\\Conversation.cs:line 108
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Sample.FormBot.MessagesController.<Post>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\\FormSqlTest1-src\\Controllers\\MessagesController.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

The error: "String or binary data would be truncated."

But i am just typing in e.g single hello

Any suggestions...really appreciate any help here. Thanks

Comment: I am a SQL person and not a Bot Framework person but this is being logged as a SQL issue so I am taking a stab at trying to help you. As you have demonstrated, the conversation events from the user are being logged but not the Bot chat events. What I think is happening is that you need to embed the Bot chat events in the client code. Please see this blog post, as it should help you construct the correct conversation stack: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/

Comment: There's an unhandled error in your bot code. Run your bot locally in debug mode and set breakpoints to see where the error is occurring. If you want to debug with a channel rather than Emulator then try using [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thanks for the suggestion. I have done that but i cannot seem to find any errors. Am i missing something? appreciate your help

Comment: Make sure you've set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: @KyleDelaney i debugged as you suggested and got the error message-sql exception as seen in the update. Any suggestions on resolution? Appreciate your time and effort

Comment: `String or binary data would be truncated` means that the data you are trying to insert is too big for the column you are inserting it into. The quickest workaround for this is to make sure your `varchar` columns are all `varchar(4000)`. You might find that it's not writing what you think it is. If you're missing a `ToString()` then it will write a string representation of the class / object.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: i have tried that-changing it to varchar(4000), still no luck

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in `LogAsync` so you could see the messages your bot is trying to log?

Comment: The user input message gets logged in the database.However the message that is outputted by the bot is not

Answer (score 0):

I've actually encountered SQL truncation errors before, though not while using the Bot Framework. It's very important to make note of the maximum length of your `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` columns so you can make sure everything being written to those columns falls within the limits. If necessary, you should truncate the strings yourself before sending them to the database.

Once you've determined the maximum length of your columns, set a breakpoint in your LogAsync method so you can see the details of each activity as it's being logged. You say you're only typing short messages like "hello" but remember it's not your messages but rather the bot's that are failing to log. Since it's unclear what the operative difference is between the messages your bot sends when it's running in the emulator versus a different channel, pay attention to `fromId` and `toId` as well, particularly if those columns in your table have different lengths. Different channels will generate ID's differently, and in Emulator the bot's ID is usually only one digit long.

TL;DR: Find out the maximum lengths of the `fromId` and `toId` and `message` columns in your `userChatLog` table, then debug your code and see how long the values are when it breaks.